# SSDT - Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Remote debugging is not supported

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I am logging into SQL Server 2019 from SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 Offline Installer.  The login is using Windows Authentication as the local admin.  Who is in the sysadmin group.

I try and debug a stored procedure but receive the error

> Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not connect to computer '127.0.0.1'. Remote debugging is not supported

If I run this query, it appears I am a sysadmin so should have access.

```
select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER  ('sysadmin') returns 1
```

I have tried using (local)/127.0.0.1.  Turning off firewalls.  Running VS2017 with Admin elevation.

Why am I here?  Because SSMS 18 doesn't support T-SQL debugging (!?).  And apparently SSMS 17.19.1 showed an Error 15 when trying to to various actions on 2019.

Is there some option I need to enable to permit access from SSDT?  I've looked at the database options but see nothing about debugging.

Regular queries work, just not debugging T-SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to install the VS2019 tools and the SSDT installed with that.

The T-SQL debugger in that works instantly and without having to try *anything* at all.  Just how things should be.

I used the 2017 version first because I wanted to use an offline installer... which is only available in the 2017 flavor.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15)

If only SSMS 18 supported T-SQL debugging.